# Using multiple constant fields

Tags: java

Apart from `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, how do I also chose `Pattern.MULTILINE` in the call to [Pattern.compile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.regex.Pattern.MULTILINE)?

```
Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("Hi", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: do you want to use `CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `MULTILINE` in the same Pattern?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to use both in the same pattern.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, and so I changed my answer to a community wiki. For more similar duplicate questions, and a decent search strategy, please check out [this Google search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+pattern+compile+multiple+flags+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are int flags, a bit-mask per the [Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String,int)), and so using bitwise-or, `|`, should work.

> flags - Match flags, a bit mask that may include CASE_INSENSITIVE, MULTILINE, DOTALL, ...

For example:

```
Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("Hi", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

---

To find many similar questions and answers, please check out this Google search link:

- [java pattern compile multiple flags site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+pattern+compile+multiple+flags+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: does this mean `CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `MUTLILINE` ?

Comment: @YCF_L: yes it should

Comment: Changed to community wiki